# Typescript `Pick` unexpectedly allows any property value

Tags: typescript

Here's a simple type I compiled with TS4.1.3:

```
interface Foo {
    [key: string]: any;
    bar: 'baz';
}
```

This should allow any value to any property except for `bar`, which is limited to a single value. So I can't do `const x: Foo = { bar: 'asdfadsf' }` for example. This is exactly as I expected.

I then do this:

```
type Bar = Pick<Foo, string>;
```

Unless I misunderstand how `Pick` works, this is supposed to be a no-op as all the keys are in `string`, including `bar`.

However to my surprise `const x: Bar = { bar: 'asdfadsf' }` **does** compile.

Only if I change the definition of `Bar`to `Pick<Foo, string & 'bar'>;` does it become a true no-op.

Where am I going wrong?

P.s.: obviously this is a MWE, the actual scenario involves React and other third party libraries, and ultimately I can force the correct type signature, I just want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand this, you have to look at the definition of `Pick` and what it is doing step by step.

This is the type that typescript is applying behind the scenes:

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { 
  [P in K]: T[P]; 
}
```

So your type:

```
type Bar = Pick<Foo, string>;
```

is really:

```
type Bar = {
  [P in string]: Foo[P];
}
```

`Foo[string]` is `any` even though `Foo['bar']` is `baz`.
There is only one signature here, so it gets simplified to a basic string index signature:

```
type Bar = {
  [x: string]: any;
}
```

When you change it to `Pick<Foo, string & 'bar'>` that is the same as `Pick<Foo, 'bar'>`.  This no longer matches the string index signature, so you get a type which just includes the defined key `bar`:

```
type Bar = {
    bar: 'baz';
}
```

Perhaps the truest no-op would be to `Pick` the two signatures separately and combine them:

```
type Bar = Pick<Foo, 'bar'> & Pick<Foo, string>;
```

becomes:

```
type Bar = {
    bar: 'baz';
} & {
    [x: string]: any;
}
```